# Software packages to create graphs or charts from a database full of numbers?

Tags: database, postgresql, web-applications, graph, charts

I have a device which generates a bunch of statistics once per second.  All of the statistics are stored in a PostgreSQL database on a Ubuntu server.

I'd like to create a web interface to prompt the user for a time range and which values to graph.  I'm also thinking this kind of thing is common when people have databases full of numbers, so it must already exist.  Problem is I don't know what terms to google to find relevant software packages.  So far, the only 2 I've found are [php5-rrd](http://pecl.php.net/package/rrd), and [Carbon/Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/carbon).

The PHP5-RRD solution seems simple enough, though I'm worried I'll be needlessly re-inventing the wheel.  Can anyone recommend other similar software packages that can help generate a bunch of "live" charts or graphs with a web front-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing things in a heavy PostgreSQL database, I did eventually change my app to use RRD (round robin database).  Lots of ways to easily get and store information in RRDs.

```
# on Ubuntu:
sudo apt-get install rrdtool
```

Once I had my RRD files, it was trivial to use the usual RRD tools combined with PHP and the free Google Charts to generate the many different graphs I needed.  Google Charts by itself is an amazing project worth highlighting:  https://developers.google.com/chart/

Answer (score 2):

Try this d3.js [tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/). Depending on your needs it might solve your problem with a way simpler solution than whatever you were thinking.

Edit: if you want to learn the very basics of d3.js, I recommend Scott Murray's [tutorials](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can try:

- [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/)
- [Saiku](http://meteorite.bi/saiku)
- [Shiny (RStudio)](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/)

Or you can google [charting library](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=charting%20library) or try something from [this article](http://selection.datavisualization.ch/)